# Игнорирование файлов при подключении библиотеки composer

Tags: git, composer

Сделал библиотеку, залил её в gitlab

Хочу чтобы при установке библиотеки `composer require "myname/mylib":"dev-master"` исключался каталог /tests, .git/ и ещё пару файлов

Возможно я путаю, и composer такое не воспринимает, но я в файле .gitattributes добавил следующий код

```
/tests export-ignore
/some-file.ext export-ignore
```

Всё равно при подключении библиотеки эти файлы появляются, находил статью нужно `composer install --prefer-dist` выполнять, но тоже не помогла такая попытка установки библиотеки

Как побороть подскажите? Желательно подружить composer и .gitatributes

Я посмотрел популярные библиотеки, у них только .gitattributes прописан с исключениями

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Опция `export-ignore` файла `.gitattributes` используется при создании архива командой `git archive`. Попробуйте создать архив из своей библиотеки, размещенной на приватной VCS командой: `git archive --remote username@example.com:/path/to/repo.git -o /tmp/mylib.zip master` и распакуйте его - вы увидете, что файлы/папки, указанные Вами в файле `.gitattributes` - отсутствуют. Папку с индексом `.git` указывать в `.gitattributes` не нужно - в архив она не включается.

У вас библиотека находится на приватном VCS, который подключен в файле `composer.json` через настройки раздела `"repositories": []`. В таком случае при установке пакета, вне зависимости от установленных параметров --`prefer-source` или `--prefer-dist` для `composer require`, он будет устанавлен с помощью клонирования указанной ветки и поэтому опции `export-ignore` файла `.gitattributes` не будут использованы.

=

Вы можете "побороть" это, разместив вашу библиотеку из приватного проекта в репозитории с типом `composer` на платном [ресурсе](https://repo.packagist.com) или создать собственный, на своем ресурсе.

Я опишу вариант с размещением репозитория на http-сервере (можно также, в подходящих случаях, разместить репозиторий локально, на хосте разработки).

Чтобы создать собственный composer-репозиторий нужно:

- разместить два файл на http-сервере: `packages.json` и файл с zip-архивом библиотеки(созданный командой `git archive`)
- в файл `composer.json`(папка проекта) добавить собственный репозиторий с типом `composer`

Пример содержимого  файла `packages.json`:

```
{
  "packages": {
    "myname/mylib": {
      "dev-master": {
        "name": "myname/mylib",
        "version": "dev-master",
        "dist": {
          "url": "https://example.com/downloads/myname/dev-master/mylib.zip",
          "type": "zip"
        },
        "source": {
          "type": "git",
          "url": "username@example.com:/path/to/mylib.git",
          "reference": "master"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Архив пакета создается командой:

```
git archive --remote username@example.com:/path/to/mylib.git -o ./mylib.zip master
```

Созданный composer-репозиторий добавляется в проект командой:

```
composer config repositories.example '{"type": "composer", "url": "https://example.com/path/to/folder"}'
```

где `/path/to/folder` - это путь до папки, в которой размещен файл `packages.json`

Теперь вы сможете устанавливать пакет из дистрибутива(опция --prefer-dist - по-умолчанию) - подготовленного архива (файл mylib.zip) или, для активной разработки, клонированием его из VCS-репозитория (опция --prefer-source)

Comment: Спасибо больше! В принципе такое подходит и я уже начал делать, только возникла проблема с авторизацией когда пытаешься из архива подключить проект. Gitlab ругается на отсутствие файла https://gitlab.com/users/sign_in.zip, но это уже другая история